# Lower bound on distance between ordered statistic

Tags: quantiles, order-statistics, probability-inequalities

I have found the following inequality in a manuscript:

Let $S_{t}^{i}$ and $S_{t}^{i^{\prime }}$ denote the $i/N$-th and $i^{\prime }/N$-th cross sectional order statistics. We require:
\begin{align}
\inf_{t\leq T}\inf_{i,i^{\prime }}\left\vert S_{t}^{i}-S_{t}^{i^{\prime }}\right\vert \geq \sigma \frac{\left\vert i-i^{\prime }\right\vert }{N^{1+\varepsilon }}
\end{align}
where:
\begin{align}
\sigma^{2}=\inf_{i\leq N}\mathrm{var}\left( S_{i,t-1}\right). \label{eq:sigma-under}
\end{align}
and $\varepsilon \geq 0$. In particular, if $S_{t}^i$ are iid, the inequality holds with $\varepsilon =0$, as the distance between the order statistics is of order $1/N$.

I understand that this is an assumption, but would anyone be able to explain it better? For example, why is the distance between iid variables of order $N$ in general? And why for non iid variables is it required that $\varepsilon \geq 0$? Doesn't this contrast with the Lipschitz continuity condition?

Comment: There is something odd here -- the LHS of the inequality depends on $T$, while the RHS of the inequality depends on $t$, because $\sigma$ depends on $t$. Should the $\sigma$ actually be $\sigma\!_{\,_T}$ and defined by $$\sigma_T^2=\inf_{i\le N}\text{var}(S_{i,\,T-1})\ ?$$